# How to create an orphan branch using tortoisegit?

Tags: git-branch, tortoisegit

How to create an orphan branch using tortoisegit?

I know I can use the command:

```
git checkout --orphan BRANCH_NAME
```

Because I am very lazy, I prefer to do it  using only a mouse. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating an orphan branch is not possible in TortoiseGit as of 2.2.0.

See https://tortoisegit.org/issue/1090

Comment: Feel free to provide a pull request.